# JSON is undefined Using json.js

Tags: jquery, html, json, twitter-bootstrap

I am using json for specific operations but when i am try to use in i.e 7 it is giving me the error of

```
'JSON' is undefined
```

I have searched for that and used "json.js" in my HTML page directly that seems to be

```
<head>    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style/bootstrape/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style/bootstrape/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="jquery/json.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

But it's giving me the error of

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'exec'
```

and also has stopped working in firefox and chrome. Sometimes my bootstrape controls are also not working with this.

I am also using `$(window).scroll(function () { //some stuff });` for scrollling and it's also giving me the error in that.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have resolved it by ample of try, replaced the `json.js` to `json2.js`

JS

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js

HTML

```
<head>   
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style/bootstrape/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style/bootstrape/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/json.js"></script>
</head>
```